# sshfs through two hops?

Tags: linux, ssh, mount, ssh-tunneling, sshfs

I want to mount a folder in a remote location to /mnt/volume on my mac but this folder is usually accessed through a login server myname@server-login.com using SSH like `ssh -A -Y -o myname@server-login.com` (the -A is necessary as it uses the same SSH key for subsequent hops) and then once on this server I do `ssh -A -Y -o myname@server-main.com`. I want to mount a folder in this server-main to my mac. How do I do this?

I have verified I can mount a folder on the server-login like so: 
`sudo sshfs -o allow_other,defer_permissions,IdentityFile=~/.ssh/id_rsa myname@server-login.com:/home/users/myname /mnt/volume`
So my sshfs is working.

I tried this method https://www.larkinweb.co.uk/computing/mounting_file_systems_over_two_ssh_hops.html
Where I did `ssh -f myname@server-login.com -L 2223:server-main.com:22 -N`
and then `sudo sshfs -p 2223 myname@server-main.com:/ /mnt/volume`
But it comes back with `remote host has disconnected`.

Answer (score 1):

In the article you are quoting there are two commands. The first,

```
$ ssh -f userB@systemB -L 2222:systemC:22 -N
```

establishes a tunnel between the local host and `systemB`; requests made to `localhost:2222` are forwarded to port `22` on `systemC`.

Hence, to mount the `/remote/path/` (that sits on `systemC`) on `localhost` you have to connect to `localhost:2222`, as in the second command:

```
$ sshfs -p 2222 userC@localhost:/remote/path/ /mnt/localpath/
```

But in your question you are trying to connect to `systemC:2223`.
It should be, instead:

```
$ ssh -f myname@server-login.com -L 2223:server-main.com:22 -N
$ sudo sshfs -p 2223 myname@localhost:/ /mnt/volume
```

Comment: Thanks - I think I can use 2222 actually. So because I want mount a specific folder accessed through server-main, I did `sudo sshfs -p 2222 myname@localhost:/group/data /mnt/volume`. It did something, but now I can't access the folder on my mac - /mnt/volume disappears and accessing through the command line it gives me "no such file or directory". Unmounting brings me back the folder...

Comment: 1) Port: you can choose the one you like most, as long as it's not already in use. 2) You probably don't want to run `sshfs` as root; you can run it as your user, just make sure to pick as mount point a directory you can write to (other users won't be able to access it). 3) That is how mounting works: on `/mnt/volume/` you will have the remote, mounted, directory, and the local content of `/mnt/volume` will not be accessible. Choose a different mount point if this is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use the option `ssh_command`:

```
sshfs :/mnt/volume -o ssh_command='ssh userB@systemB -t ssh userC@systemC'
```

Unmount with:

```
fusermount -u /mnt/volume
```

Comment: Not sure if it has always been the case, but for me I need _no spaces_ between the colon and remote directory; with a space, for me it fails, but it works without the space, as in `sshfs :/mnt/volume -o ssh_command=...`. Thanks Alex, this was just what I needed today!